# embed a footer at the bottom of a div

Tags: css

How do i embed

```
<div id="site-wrapper">
   <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

to appear at the bottom of the div always .

```
#footer{
 position:relative;
 height: auto;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You need:

```
#site-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: +1 for the right answer. Also note that specifying `0px` is not needed as `0` is the same in every unit. So `bottom: 0;` does exactly the same and is 2 chars shorter (also looks better in my opinion). Not a world of difference, but useful for mobile sites where every bit counts.

Answer (score 0):

```
#footer { 
position: absolute; 
bottom: 0px; 
}
```

Should work.